# How does one add a callback or get a notification when play is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have added a video to my view using the following code:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("etude", withExtension:"mp4")
player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)  
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
playerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: videoWidth, height: videoHeight)
self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)
```

I have some other events to trigger when the user taps the play button on the player. Is there a good way to set a call back when that happens or perhaps add an observer to detect it?

Comment: NSBundle.mainBundle() has a method URLForResource(WithExtension:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can register for Key-Value-Observing for playerViewController.player.rate.

Looks something like

```
self.player.addObserver(observer:self,keyPath:"rate",options:0,context:nil)
```

Then implement

```
func observeValueForKeyPath(_ keyPath: String?,
                   ofObject object: AnyObject?,
                     change change: [String : AnyObject]?,
                    context context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
  if(self.player.rate==1){
     print("playing")
  }else if(self.player.rate == 0){
     print("stopped")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks beyowulf. I think we are on the right track. I am still running into an issue though when passing 0 to options. From what I can see It should be valid as per the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSKeyValueObservingOptions) but I am getting a cannot convert Int error.